# What path is represented by "../" in python?

Tags: python

In this code:

```
import scipy.io as scpio
scpio.loadmat('../data/file.mat')
```

Which path is represented by `'../'`, and how can I print this path?

I am running anaconda, and I assumed that `'../'` would represent the home directory in parentheses before each anaconda command prompt line, but that guess was incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of `os.path.realpath`

```
from os import path as op
op.realpath('../')
```

the `../` usually means the directory above your `cwd`

Comment: `../` is not your current working directory, it is a level above. A single `./` would be your current working directory.

Comment: The wording is ambiguous and misleading. I edited to say "directory above your cwd"

Comment: state farm truly is always by my side.